# Twitpic API: image comments

Tags: twitter, twitpic

Does anyone know whether there's a way to retrieve the latest comments posted against an image on Twitpic - I can't find anything in their API. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Look up the original tweet on twitter. Once you have that, then ask twitter for all of the replies to that tweet. Then just filter out the @person tag and you should more or less have it sorted!

Joe

Comment: Thanks Joe - this is the conclusion I reached also :) But the problem is twitter only shows recent tweets, so old comments will be lost unless I save them onto a secondary database... still thinking :)

Comment: you could ask twitpic if they could provide the api for comments